# Not getting response from Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Using Alamofire for JSON response from remote.
I have had a very weird issue. While running my app on a device connected through cable is working fine and getting all response. But when the device gets disconnected through cable response time getting increased to 5 minutes to 30 minutes and if I connect the device to charging or to MacBook again it's work fine but stuck if not connected.

```
    func getData()
    {
        let baseUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "")
        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]
        Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON
        { response in
            switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):
                    if response.result.value != nil{
                        let jsonData = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                        print(jsonData)
                    }
                case .failure(_):
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to get the response quickly on a simulator..?

Comment: Can you share your api request. ?

Comment: @dtanwar Where, I am not able to see any api request.

Comment: @Faiz it' working fine on simulator.

Comment: @dtanwar I need the full information like base url, path, any required token, Then I can check. Your code look fine.

Comment: Soory @Naresh but i can't share that . Thanks for your help

Comment: You're adding the JSON Content-Type, but you're using the URLEncoding parameter encoding. That's probably wrong; figure out which one you're supposed to use.

Comment: @JonShier Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any other class for Session manager? If yes then that may cause problem. So remove that one.

Comment: Yes i am using a Download Manager class , that is using URLSessionTaskDelegate and URLSessionDownloadDelegate. Tried and it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

can you share your api request ?.

One possible solution to add Transport security as:

Add this code in info.plist, inside the root  tag

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. You can comment on the question to ask for more information.

Comment: @Soroush I have already, commented, and this may be the possible answer. By the way, why are you worry about it ? It's not your problem

Comment: Turning off ATS is a generally bad idea, and recommending it without it specifically being the issue is not a good idea.